# Нужна помощь с размещением фото в ImageView

Tags: java, android, uri, imageview

С фронтальной камеры фото размещается на боку, а с передней - вообще не размещается (пустой ImageView). Как сделать чтобы фотографии размещались нормально?

Метод onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.out);

    mIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outImageView);
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    mIV.setImageURI(uriSavedImage);

    Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.outButton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Result.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```